# Difference of lengths

Tags: errors, calculations, lengths

This should be a very basic problem, but I can't find it anywhere:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fp}

\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\newlength{\radiustai} 
\setlength{\radiustai}{1cm}
\newlength{\thickness} 
\setlength{\thickness}{0.3\radiustai} 
\newlength{\iradiusbagua} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]

  \iradiusbagua=\radiustai-\thickness

  \draw (0,0) -- (\iradiusbagua,\thickness);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Latex complains that it's `missing a number, treated as zero`.

How can I compute the difference between two lengths in Latex (I was hoping "fixed point arithmetic" would understand the `-` sign)?

Comment: Would using the `calc` package be acceptable - or is there more reason for using `fixedpointarithmetic`, for this example `\setlength{\iradiusbagua}{\radiustai-\thickness}` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @Dai Bowen The `calc` package is perfectly acceptable.  I just thought `fixed point arithmetic` would have more options for calculations, but I actually don't need more options. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is with `fixed point arithmetic`, but you have other alternatives:

1. Use `\setlength{\iradiusbagua}{\radiustai-\thickness}`, although this solution requires the `calc` package.
2. Use `\pgfmathsetmacro\iradiusbaguas{\radiustai-\thickness}`, although this solution requires you to manually add `pt`, otherwise Tikz will think it's in `cm`. This requires `pgfkeys` plus `pgfutil-common` and `pgfmath.code`, but since you're using Tikz, that means you don't have to use any extra packages.
3. Use `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\iradiusbaguas{\radiustai-\thickness}`, which is in my opinion the best solution since it doesn't require any additional packages in your case since you're using Tikz and it already comes with `pt` since it's a length calculation.

I used relative coordinates so that the example is clearer to understand.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc} % needed for the length calculation...
%\usepackage{fp}

%\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\newlength{\radiustai} 
\setlength{\radiustai}{1cm}
\newlength{\thickness} 
\setlength{\thickness}{0.3\radiustai} 
\newlength{\iradiusbagua} 
\setlength{\iradiusbagua}{\radiustai-\thickness} % ...here


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\iradiusbaguas{\radiustai-\thickness}
\pgfmathsetmacro\iradiusbaguass{\radiustai-\thickness}
%
\draw (0,0) --++ (\iradiusbagua,\thickness) node[right] {\the\iradiusbagua~\verb!\setlength!};
\draw[red] (0,.5) --++ (\iradiusbaguas,\thickness) node[right] {\iradiusbaguas~\verb!\pgfmathsetlength!};
\draw[green] (0,1) --++ (\iradiusbaguass pt,\thickness) node[right] {\iradiusbaguass pt~\verb!\pgfmathset!};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ended up using the third solution. For some odd reason I still got an error with the first one (and didn't try the second one).

Comment: @andyc is your distribution up to date?

Comment: Very much up to date. I'm on TexLive 2016 on Ubuntu and I update it almost daily from the repositories. I believe the fact that `calc` didn't work is because I was actually trying to do some extra calculations which I didn't add in my MWE in order to keep it minimal. Maybe you can't divide by the square root of 2 inside of `\setlength`?

Comment: @Andyc Paste here in the comments the calculation you were trying to do. I'm curious to see that.

Comment: Here it is: `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\basedistance{(2*\iradiusbagua/sqrt(2+sqrt(2))-sqrt(2)*\thickness)}`. This works great. Inside of `\setlength` I couldn't make it work.